# Default user-specific properties

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, msbuild

I'm working on a project that requires a property named `$(LibPath)` to be set. This value should be set by a plugin, however it is saved in the `projectname.vcxproj.user` file. This is a problem for when someone has this file removed (through `git clean` for example) or someone new starting on the project.

In order to have a default value, I've created a Property Sheet which is impoted in the project file at the very top.

```
<PropertyGroup Label="UserMacros">
  <LibPath Condition="'$(LibPath)' == ''">PathToLib</LibPath>
</PropertyGroup>
<ItemGroup>
  <BuildMacro Include="LibPath">
    <Value>$(LibPath)</Value>
  </BuildMacro>
</ItemGroup>
```

It now works for everyone whose path matches the default. When it doesn't, they can change it from within VS by going to Property Manager -> Properties Sheet file -> User Macros.

Now the remaining issue is that when this path doesn't match and needs to be changed, the value inside the Propety Sheet is changed too.

**So my question**: Is there a way to define a property that can be edited from within VS, and that is then saved in the `vcxproj.user` file (or any other user-specific file which overrides the default value)?

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to define a property that can be edited from within VS that is saved in the vcxproj.user file?

AFAIK, I am afraid the reason why you can not edit the defined property in Visual Studio when that path does not match is that **the vcxproj.user file is imported after than the Propety Sheet**.

If we create a property sheet, we will get following import file `TestSheet.props` in the project file:

```
  <ImportGroup Label="PropertySheets" Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|Win32'">
    <Import Project="$(UserRootDir)\Microsoft.Cpp.$(Platform).user.props" Condition="exists('$(UserRootDir)\Microsoft.Cpp.$(Platform).user.props')" Label="LocalAppDataPlatform" />
    <Import Project="TestSheet.props" />
  </ImportGroup>
```

The `vcxproj.user` file is imported by following Import：

```
 <Import Project="$(VCTargetsPath)\Microsoft.Cpp.targets" />
```

This file is under the `TestSheet.props` in the project file:

[image]

In this case, MSBuild will use the value of `$(LibPath)` in the vcxproj.user file replace the value in the propety sheet. So it only works for everyone whose path matches the default, if you change the value by going to Property Manager -> Properties Sheet file -> User Macros, the value will be overwrite by the next import file `Microsoft.Cpp.targets`.

To resolve this issue, you can comment all the `<Import Project="TestSheet.props" />`lines in the project file, and add this line after import `Microsoft.Cpp.targets` file:

```
<Import Project="$(VCTargetsPath)\Microsoft.Cpp.targets" />
<Import Project="TestSheet.props" />
```

With this setting, if you change the value in the User Macros, this value will overwrite the value in the `vcxproj.user` file.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Maybe I wasn't too clear, because I want the `.user` file to override the default value. The Property Sheet should act like a default value. When the user changes it, I'd like the new value to appear as a property in the `.user` file, which then overrides the default.

Comment: @Broxzier, Got it. if you want overwrite that value in the .user file, you can create a custom task to replace that value:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/662912/how-can-one-replace-the-extension-of-a-file-path-stored-in-an-msbuild-property. Or using PowerShell to replace that value.